# Qual a melhor hospedagem para se manter um sistema?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Olá.

Estamos desenvolvendo um sistema de Gerenciamento de Tarefas (na empresa em que faço estágio) e agora teremos a necessidade de hospedar o sistema na web.

- O sistema é feito com muito JavaScript/jQuery, PHP e utiliza o banco de dados MySQL.
- O sistema será utilizado por uns 100 usuários e as interações serão feitas praticamente o tempo todo (diariamente).

**Minha dúvida é a seguinte:**

Qual tipo de plano de hospedagem teremos que procurar para armazenar o sistema sem que aconteça lentidão, falhas no processamento e travamentos ?

- Nós estamos iniciando nessa área de Desenvolvimento Web e não temos muita noção de hospedagem de sistemas.

**A imagem abaixo, é mostrada em um plano de hospedagem que oferece os seus serviços.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentre as opções mostradas na imagem, devemos nos basear em que na hora da escolha do pacote do plano de hospedagem ?

Se puderem explicar cada campo (que é mostrado nessa imagem), eu ficaria grato.

**Abaixo, é uma imagem do sistema.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse sistema será utilizado por vários usuário e sempre terá interação com o banco de dados (MySQL) com o uso de jQuery/JavaScript e PHP.

Gostaria de ter uma noção de qual "pacote de hospedagem" utilizar. Pois não temos muita noção disso. D

Mencionaram que a pergunta foi fora de escopo, mas acho que está dentro do escopo da TAG "Hospedagem", que existe aqui no Stack.

Desde já, agradeço. Obrigado!

Comment: Qual a ação do usuário que é mais custosa (CPU e Memória) para o servido? Nesta ação, quantos Kbs o servidor enviou para o cliente? Qual a previsão de crescimento do banco por mês nos próximos anos? Tem funcionalidades de upload de arquivos (ex. pdf, word, excel...)? Estas respostas vão lhe ajudar em parte do problema.

Comment: O banco de dados aumentará futuramente (próximos meses) e terá sim funcionalidade de upload de arquivos, mas não será muito constante.

Comment: Tags não definem escopo. O site é apenas sobre programação, e ferramentas quando usadas para a programação em si. Suporte de TI, hospedagem, coisas que dependem de opinião, mesmo que um programador use (como a altura ideal do monitor, teclado adequado e "melhor cor de fundo de tela para se programar") também [não estão no escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Então pra que servem as tags e sobre o que eu poderia falar utilizando a tag "hospedagem" ? É só um esclarecimento mesmo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, Thiago, tudo bem?

Abaixo forneço uma breve explicação sobre cada uma das informações de plano que se veem na imagem, elas são quase idênticas às noções de funcionamento de um computador, com a diferença de serem "virtuais".

**Sistema operacional:** refere-se ao sistema que será usado pelo seu servidor: Windows Server ou uma distro Linux (geralmente Debian, Ubuntu...).

**vCPU:** é uma unidade de processamento virtual, o processador virtual alocado para a sua hospedagem compartilhada.

**Memória RAM:** é a memória que será consumida pelo servidor web (como o Apache), a execução do PHP, do SGBD e de todas as outras rotinas, como firewall, agendador de tarefas e etc.

**Espaço em disco:** é a memória que será consumida pelos arquivos do seu site, ou seja, suas páginas PHP/HTML, arquivos de imagens, folhas de estilos CSS e scripts JS, por exemplo.

**Velocidade (link dedicado):** pode ser que a hospedagem até esteja usando com outro significado, mas não vejo outro além da velocidade de acesso do servidor à internet, isso seria como a velocidade do seu plano de internet.

**IP dedicado:** um único número de IP exclusivo para o seu servidor virtual.

**Backup:** certamente um serviço de cópia de arquivos e banco de dados automático oferecido pela hospedagem.

Enfim, simplificando, veja como sendo as informações de um computador, pois na verdade são, a diferença é que em hospedagens compartilhadas tudo é virtual, ou seja, você não terá uma máquina com 3 vCPUs (processadores virtuais), e sim o direito à usar uma velocidade de processamento maior que é fornecida por um ou mais processadores físicos e divididos entre várias contas de hospedagem como a sua.

Minha recomendação é que você não fique de início preocupado com isso, é claro que desempenho é importante, mas de imediato, sendo novo na área, publique o seu projeto e analise constantemente o uso de recursos e como cada novo usuário que entra os consome.

Pense: não é muito melhor publicar o seu aplicativo e durante o prazo de 2 à 3 semanas avaliar o consumo de recursos por parte do servidor? Se há gargalos ou se escolheu um plano "que sobra demais"?